# Storing push notifications locally on app

Tags: java, android, push-notification, sharedpreferences

Currently, I'm able to display, push notifications and able to display on Recycler View. However, whenever I close the app and reopen, the push notifications will be gone.

I read that using SharedPreferences will save but it doesn't save my notifications and I don't really know how to implement it into my codes. I want my notifications to be displayed when I open the app.

Another problem that I have just encountered with SharedPreferencecs is that each new push notification I send will replace the old notifications. For example, if I send a notification message "test" and the second notification message "test2", test2 will overwrite the test. I was able to successfully display all the notifications, but after implementing SharedPreferences, I get the overwritten values.

[image]

**NotificationFragment.java**

```
public class NotificationFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView test;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<Notification> notificationList;
    private BroadcastReceiver activityReceiver;
    private String MyPREFERENCES = "test";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification, container, false);


        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.notificationRecyclerview);
        notificationList = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(getContext(), notificationList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        activityReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("msg");
                String body = bundle.getString("msgBody");
                SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("notification", body);
                editor.apply();
                Log.d("body", body);
                Notification obj = new Notification(body);
                prepareNotification(obj.getBody());

            }

        };

        if (activityReceiver != null) {
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new  IntentFilter("ACTION_STRING_ACTIVITY");
            getActivity().registerReceiver(activityReceiver, intentFilter);
        }

        return v;
    }

    private void prepareNotification(String body){
        Notification obj = new Notification(body);
        notificationList.add(obj);
        mAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(getContext(), notificationList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

**NotificationAdapter.java**

```
public class NotificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.NotificationHolder> {
    private List<Notification> notificationList;
    private Context mContext;
    private String MyPREFERENCES = "test";
    public SharedPreferences prefs;


    public NotificationAdapter(Context mContext, List<Notification> notificationList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.notificationList = notificationList;
        prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    @Override
    public NotificationHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_notification, parent, false);
        return new NotificationHolder(inflatedView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final NotificationHolder holder, int position) {
        Notification notification = notificationList.get(position);
//        String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
//        holder.body.setText("Notification Message" + notification.getBody());
        holder.body.setText("Notification Message: " + prefs.getString("notification", "No notifcation"));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notificationList.size();
    }

    public class NotificationHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView body;

        public NotificationHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            body = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bodyMsg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use sqlite database

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I'm using firebase. So I have to store notifcations in database and then retrieve?

Comment: firebase is your server database, sqlite is your local database. you can use both